# Display Filterable JSON Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables, filtering

I have JSON data that is separated by the day of the week.

[image]

If the data was just listed out by just the date's and not in it's own array by day, I'd normally use datatables so that it is filterable. However, I am trying to separate the data so it has headers, like so:

[image]

With this json data, I am not sure how I would use data tables to do this and also make it filterable. Does anyone have any suggestions (plugins, etc) that I should use to display the data the way I want in a filterable environment?

This is ultimately how I would like to display the data:

```
<div id="day_of_week">August 26, 2014</div>
<div id="event">
    <span id="time">5:52 AM</span>
    <span id="event_name">Page View</span>
    <div id="hidden_data">Data: Goes here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Angularjs ngrepeat with a filter might work for you.. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: How do you know he is using angular?

Comment: I'm not using angular, but it does sound like a worthy solution to look into unless it wouldn't be worth it to use angular only for this particular purpose?

Comment: Angular is a whole framework, and not worth using it if you were to only use it for this

Comment: I didn't know he is using angular. I actually assumed he wasn't, since he didn't mention it. If he mentioned he was using it, I would have put that as an answer and not just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a Templating logic, like @Thimoty suggested, tough implemented manually since you need it to be lightweight. I'm working on a fiddle, I'll post it ASAP.

This is it: http://jsfiddle.net/23e37v18/

HTML

```
 <div id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="template" style="display: none">
    <div class="day_of_week">August 26, 2014</div>
    <div class="event">
        <span class="time"></span>
        <span class="event_name"></span>
        <div class="hidden_data"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

JQuery

```
var jsonText = '{"August 23, 2014":{"1409069553":{"Data":"Your event"},"1407859953 ":{"Data":"Your event"},"1399911153":{"Data":"Your event"}},"August 24, 2014":{"1409069553":{"Data":"Your event"},"1399911139 ":{"Data":"Your event"},"1399914139":{"Data":"Your event"}},"August 25, 2014":{"1407859953 ":{"Data":"Your event"}}}';

$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = JSON.parse(jsonText);
    for (var day in data){
        $('#content').append(day + '<br/>');
        // create block
        var blockData = data[day];
        var block = $('<div/>').addClass('event_block');

        for (var event in blockData){
            // your event block
            var eventDOM = $('#template .event').clone();

            // add content
            var date = new Date(event*1000)
            // TODO: format date for display
            $('.time', eventDOM).append(date);
            $('.time', eventDOM).append(blockData[event].Data);
            block.append(eventDOM);
        }

        $('#content').append(block);
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, that's very kind of you. Thank you @LoyaltyTechnology

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind shedding light on a possible approach to make this filterable? Through any text that is in the event classes? That's where my biggest issue lies. I didn't have a problem parsing it, just didn't know how to parse it when I want to filter results.

Comment: That is another question :) but I'll give you a hint. Accept the answer first.

Comment: here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/23e37v18/2/ . Easiest filtering is with classes, that way you can add several criteria and implement AND logic (for exemple events of Type 2 that contain some string in their description).

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. It seems a little counter-intuitive to make a whole other `filterData` array if I am going to have LOTS of data though. There will be more like 10 objects inside the time array not just `data`. I really do appreciate your help though. I hope I don't come off as unappreciative.